# Java: using TreeSet

Tags: java

I want to go over the objects inside my `TreeSet`, I can do it by making an array using `toArray` but I don't need to go over all of the objects in the Set.

How can I go over the objects in the Set (starting with the first than the second etc') ?

And another small question about `TreeSet` : Can I keep the objects in the `TreeSet` sorted (so the first object will be with the smallest key etc') ?

edit: say I have a class myInt (with int myInteger) and I want to use it in TreeSet with a different oredering than the natural one, what do I need to define in my class (myInt) to do this ?

Comment: Looks like TreeSet keeps it sorted and it looks like first() will give you the smallest, where last() gives you the largest. You can also use iterators over any collection to go through the tree.

Comment: @Matt - TreeSet keeps it sorted according to what key ?

Comment: you can create a comparator or it sorts by it's natural ordering. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: You can supply your own comparator - thats what sorts it. If you use an object that implements comparable - that will be used.

Comment: @Fortyrunner - How can I change the comparator used by the Set ?

Comment: You can pass in a new Comparator in the constructor of a TreeSet. The Java Tutorial shows how this can be done http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/sorted-set.html

Comment: @Belgi: read the documentation. It's in there. And it's there to be read. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I go over the objects in the Set

The easiest way to iterate over the items of the set is like so:

```
SortedSet<T> set = new TreeSet<T>();
for (T elem : set) {
  // use elem
}
```

> Can I keep the objects in the TreeSet sorted

`TreeSet` is automatically sorted, so you don't need to do anything.

> I have a class MyInt (with int myInteger) and I want to use it in TreeSet with a different ordering than the natural one

You have two options:

**Option 1: Make it implement [`Comparable<MyInt>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)**:

```
public class MyInt implements Comparable<MyInt> {
   public int compareTo(MyInt o) {
     // return -1 if `this` is less than `o`
     //         0 if `this` is equal to `o`
     //         1 of `this` is greater than `o`
   }
}
```

**Option 2: Supply a [`Comparator<MyInt>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) when constructing the `TreeSet`:**

```
public class MyIntCmp implements Comparator<MyInt> {
  // implement compare() and equals() as per Comparator javadoc
}
SortedSet<T> set = new TreeSet<T>(new MyIntCmp());
```

Comment: @Belgi: See the expanded answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (MySetElementType element : mytreeset) {
}
```

TreeSet always keeps the objects sorted by how the objects compareTo (Comparable interface) is implemented. (Or you can pass a separate Comparator into the TreeSet constructor.)

Answer (score 0):

Since the SetTree implements iterable you can use a regular for each loop or use the iterator directly. In the javadocs it says that it will iterate in ascending order.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#iterator()

Answer (score 0):

1. The items inside TreeSet are automatically sorted according to their
   natural ordering if you are not giving your own comparator.
2. Second thing you can define an Iterator to go through the TreeSet
   item directly without converting it to array.